# import in-app products to google play by csv with unicode descriptions

Tags: android

I've been trying to import my in-app products into google play using the csv import feature.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-bulk-add

This all works well when the file contains standard ascii characters. It falls over when the file contains unicode characters. Has anyone managed to successfully import unicode characters via csv? I have forty products in thirteen languages, I'd rather not update the unicode titles and descriptions by hand.

Thanks.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your csv file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. Note that some brain-damaged text editors (like Notepad on some versions of Windows) insist on adding a byte order mark. Don't use one of those editors; byte order marks don't belong in a UTF-8 stream.